# Does superset support master-child panels in its dashboards?

Tags: apache-superset

Looking at the open source https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset product...

Can't see any docs to suggest whether the product supports master-child filtering on its dashboards?

Example:  one report panel shows a list of customers; a second panel shows a list of invoices; clicking on a entry in the customers panel will filter the items in the invoices panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by employing a table slice, as it allows for selecting one or several entries to use as filters for the remaining slices of the dashboard. Just check the filter option when creating the table slice.

In your example, the only prerequisite is for both source tables to contain a column for the customers which is named equally and contains the same entities. But the latter I'd consider safe to assume in a well designed DB.
The customers column only needs to exist in the underlying tables, as it us used in the constructed SQL query. There is no need to display the column in the invoices slice, though.